# Rotating a seaborn subplot 90 degrees

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

How do I flip a seaborn plot vertically? I have a matplotlib subplot I want to rotate 90 degrees, and I'd prefer to use seaborn for groupings/style etc, but I can't seem to figure out how to rotate my figure.

My real data has many dimensions and time intervals (why I'd like to use seaborn), but here's an example of the figure I'm generating:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(0,10,np.pi/8)
y1 = np.sin(x)
y2 = np.sin(x+np.pi/8)
y3 = np.cos(x+np.pi/8)

d1 = {'depth_below_surface':x,
      'signal_return':y1,
      'time' : 't1',
      }

d2 = {'depth_below_surface':x,
      'signal_return':y2,
      'time' : 't2',
}

d3 = {'depth_below_surface':x,
      'signal_return':y3,
      'time' : 't3',
}

tdf1 = pd.DataFrame(data = d1)
tdf2 = pd.DataFrame(data = d2)
tdf3 = pd.DataFrame(data = d3)


df = pd.concat([tdf1, tdf2, tdf3])

fig0, ax0 = plt.subplots(figsize = (8,8)) 

graph = sns.lineplot(data = df,
                     x = 'depth_below_surface',
                     y = 'signal_return',
                     hue = 'time',
                     ax = ax0)
```

The Result:
[code output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YlgFV.png)

When I swap x and y, the lines are connected along the wrong dimension:
[swapped x and x](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IGQgh.png)

What I want is something that looks like this, though with all the ticks and labels rotated too:
[preferred outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5YUYz.png)

Comment: You probably want to add `sns.lineplot(....sort=False,  errorbar=None)`. (Also note that `sns.lineplot()` doesn't return a "graph", instead it returns the subplot on which the plot was created, i.e. `ax0`).

Comment: Since seaborn 0.12, you can change the orientation: `sns.lineplot(...., orient='y')`